# My post was deleted for plagiarizing myself

Tags: support, moderation

I have a question about my Puzzling Stack Exchange post: [Web of Spirits - a puzzle of romance](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41819/web-of-spirits-a-puzzle-of-romance)

The post in question was deleted for plagiarism. Specifically, as stated in the delete reason, for copying parts of [this post](https://reddit.com/r/puzzles/comments/3mv46v/web_of_spirits/) by qwertyu63 on Reddit. The only issue is that qwertyu63 is me. I've actually now edited that post to mention my username here. Could someone with the power to do so please fix this?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that! We've had a *lot* of issues with plagiarism recently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've undeleted your post. Thanks for confirming, and sorry about the inconvenience!